# How to implement pure client side pagination without requests to the server in react, using react-table and react-paginate components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap, react-table

I am using an array of objects that comes from the server in componentDidMount method and then I save it into the state.

If I change page size from select component everything is ok, but the page number clicks don't work.

For example,  I set the page size to 20. My data array length equal to 29, so I have 2 pages. In the react table, there are 20 rows, and selected page - number 1. When I select page 2, nothing happens. It should have shown the remaining 9 rows but nothing occurs.

I know that in general the amount of data corresponding to the page size must come from the server when click to another page occurs. But I was given the task that I should implement everything without requests to the server.

How I can implement this? Any of your help will be useful, great thanks in advance! Here is my code:

```
constructor:
    perPage: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('detailsTablePerPageOrderEdit')) || 20,
    pageRanges: [20, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000],

                 <CustomReactTable
                    columns={columnsDetails}
                    tableHeight={_.isEmpty(this.state.details) ? '25vh' : '80%'}
                    data={this.state.details}
                    onTrClick={(data) => this.handleDetailSelect(data)}
                    pageSize={this.state.perPage}
                  />
                  <PaginationRow
                    changePerPage={(pageSize) => this.onPageSizeChange(pageSize)}
                    count={this.state.details.length}
                    handlePageChange={(page) => this.handlePageChange(page)}
                    page={this.state.page}
                    perPage={this.state.perPage}
                    pageRanges={this.state.pageRanges}
                  />

        handlePageChange = (page) => {           
       this.setState({ page: page.selected + 1 }); 
          //I think, here should be some code to implement pagination
       };
onPageSizeChange = pageSize => {
    console.log(typeof pageSize);
    localStorage.setItem('detailsTablePerPageOrderEdit', pageSize);
    this.setState({
      page: 1,
      perPage: pageSize
    });
  };
```

paginationRow component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import PaginationCount from './PaginationCount';
import i18n from '../../i18n';

export default (props) => {

  if(props.count <= 0 || props.page < 0 || props.perPage < 0){
    return null;
  }


  const fromItem = (props.page - 1) * props.perPage + 1;
  let toItem = props.page * props.perPage;

  toItem = toItem > props.count ? props.count : toItem;

  const handlePageSizeChange = e => {
    props.changePerPage && props.changePerPage(e.target.value);
  };

  const pageRanges = props.pageRanges || [50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000];

  return(
    <Row>
      <div className="col padded">
        <ReactPaginate
          activeClassName="active"
          breakLabel={<a href="#!">...</a>}
          containerClassName="pagination"
          disableInitialCallback
          forcePage={props.page - 1}
          initialPage={props.page - 1}
          marginPagesDisplayed={5}
          nextLabel={i18n.t('PaginationRow.next_label')}
          onPageChange={props.handlePageChange}
          pageCount={props.count/props.perPage}
          pageRangeDisplayed={5}
          previousLabel={i18n.t('PaginationRow.previous_label')}
          subContainerClassName="pages pagination"
        />
      </div>
      {props.perPage ?
        <div className="col col-md-auto ">
          <div className="form-group">
            <select
              className="form-control paginationSelect" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"
              name="perPage"
              onChange={handlePageSizeChange}
              value={props.perPage}
            >
              {pageRanges.map(r => (<option key={r} value={r}>{r}</option>))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>  : null
      }
      <div className="col text-nowrap">
        <div className="paginationTextInfo">
          <PaginationCount
            itemFrom={fromItem}
            itemTo={toItem}
            totalCount={props.count}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Row>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to modify your array of results based on page state (current pagination page).

With F.E array.slice func:

`function paginate (array, page_size, page_number) {
  return array.slice((page_number-1) * page_size, (page_number) * page_size);
}`

Comment: Thanks. You gave me the direction. But there are much more to write inside the function and in component itself. I will mark your answer as the best answer

Comment: Hi. Can you help me with my next question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652942/how-to-understand-this-fragment-of-code-in-javascript-react